# Optimizing file write speed in R

Tags: r

I am wondering about the possibility to speed up the process of writing to a file. 
with my SSD and core i5 vPro I am getting following results for the file of 5234 KB:

```
system.time({
      write(reportData, "aaa.txt") 
})
   user  system elapsed 
   1.42    3.56   12.28
```

as well as

```
system.time({
    fileConn<-file("aaa.txt")
    writeLines(reportData, fileConn)
    close(fileConn)
})
   user  system elapsed 
   1.43    3.46   13.61
```

and

```
system.time({
    fileConn <- file("aaa.txt","w")
    cat(reportData,file=fileConn,sep="")
    close(fileConn)
})
   user  system elapsed 
   1.50    4.13   14.12
```

All of them seem to be implemented in the similar manner since the time execution is almost identical.
Is it possible to use Rcpp library, for c++ could definitely do it much faster?

**EDIT**

Without using Rcpp `writeChar` seems to be the fastest.

```
 system.time({
        fileConn<-file("aaa.txt")
        writeChar(reportData, fileConn,nchar(reportData, type = "chars"))
        close(fileConn)
 })
    user  system elapsed 
    0.01    0.14    1.31
```

Comment: *"for c++ could definitely do it much faster?"* - you can be sure that [R is ultimately calling C code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/2f2e4711ad7089f97f22c6b1ae25ba582d2e99a6/src/main/connections.c#L3650-L3718) to do any sort of writing to the filesystem, so I would not blindly make the assumption that it can be done faster in C++. That being said, the `data.table` package recently added `fwrite`, which may be calling *more* optimized C code, but you would have to benchmark this (hint: use a proper benchmarking tool like the `microbenchmark` package).

Comment: Use [`fwrite` which is parallelised](http://blog.h2o.ai/2016/04/fast-csv-writing-for-r/) from the [development version of data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).